# How to set MarkerOptions in gmaps4rails (optimized = false)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

My custom icons in gmaps4rails are not displaying correctly.  I need to set MarkerOptions to optimized = false:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

I have looked at the documentation for gmaps4rails but I can't seem to find the correct place to set this option.  Any ideas?

Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put whatever option you desire as documented [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map-Apis).

Simply use the `raw` key.